# How can you automatically rebuild an APK OnBuild of a UITest project for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, apk

I'd like to ensure I have a fresh build of an APK before my UI tests start.  I think I can accomplish this using build targets in the csprojec file, but I'm pretty unfamiliar with messing around with those.

My situation is, I am writing a ton tests, which require me to add new AutomationId properties in xaml.  To run my tests previous, I used the InstalledApp() method to point to the emulator's apk, but that requires me to run/install the apk after I change the xaml each time.  I'd like to change to using ApkFile(), but building the solution doesn't actually produce a new APK.  Whether it be through build events or some other mechanism, I'd like to know best practices regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Xamarin.UITest won't compile the application and create the Apk for you.It will deploy an existing APK to an attached device or an instance of the Android emulator that's already running.

Comment: I understand that -- I would like to figure out a solution to build a fresh apk so that the UITest can deploy a new copy of that apk to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

turns out, I needed to add a windows environment PATH variable to the visual studio version of msbuild.exe, then use

```
msbuild /p:AndroidBuildApplicationPackage=True "$(SolutionDir)\PROJECT-NAME.Droid.csproj"
```

previously I was getting a 9009 error, which I mistakenly thought was a file not found error for my csproj file, it was actually for the msbuild exe file, which is the reason for the PATH variable.